# To narrow downwards

Tags: prepositions

I want to cut plywood into the shape where its sides narrow downwards. So that the bottom edge of it will be narrower than the top edge.

> I want to cut this plywood with the upper side that narrows downward.

> I want to cut this plywood from the lower side narrow  to the upper side wider.

I want to ask if it would be mean the same when I make this sentence with“ from…to” or “with”?

Comment: You might want the plywood to [taper](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/taper) from 26 inches at the top to 14 inches at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"With" and "from...to" can both be used, but not like this.

Neither of your sentences is correct because the upper/lower <del>side</del> end doesn't change size. The *whole piece* changes size as you *move away from* the upper/lower end.

Further, "with" and "from...to" aren't interchangeable elements. They can both be used in the same sentence:

> I want to cut this plywood **with** it narrowing **from the top to the bottom**.

Though more natural would be:

> I want to cut this **piece of** plywood **so that** it narrows from the top to the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

I think you might need the word [taper](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/taper)

Comment: If I don’t use “taper” would the both sentences mean the same?

Comment: No, your versions are not idiomatic.